# How can I get a div that moves using arrow keys to not be able to go off screen?

Tags: javascript, css, event-listener, pong, arrow-keys

I want to make a pong game using HTML, CSS and javascript. I started with making a player and I got it to move using the arrow keys but it can go outside the screen which creates the sidebar. I want it to not be able to go off the screen.
Here is the javascript code:

```
const right = document.getElementById("right");

const player = document.createElement("player");
player.classList.add("player");
right.appendChild(player);

player.style.top = "300px";
player.style.left = 5;

let moveBy = 10;
window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  switch (event.key) {
    case "ArrowUp":
      player.style.top =
        parseInt(player.style.top) - moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      player.style.top =
        parseInt(player.style.top) + moveBy + "px";
      break;
  }
});
```

I tried adding if statements but it did not work, I have also tried to google it but I have not found the right answer for this.

Comment: You did not set the boundary at all. Is the browser area your boundary? or is there a specific DIV for the "move zone"?

Comment: The browser should be the boundary, I tried adding it using if statements, and I got it to stay inside but if I were to try and run it on another screen it would not work because the screens are different sizes. I don't know how to get the height of the browser area. I tried using screen.height, but that returns the height of the whole screen, not just the browser page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `position: absolute;` to make `top` setting work.

```js
player.style.position = "absolute";
```

Then set the range of top (0 ~ `window.innerHeight`)

```js
let top,
  max = window.innerHeight - 30;
switch (event.key) {
  case "ArrowUp":
    top = parseInt(player.style.top) - moveBy;
    break;
  case "ArrowDown":
    top = parseInt(player.style.top) + moveBy;
    break;
}
player.style.top = top > max ? max : top < 0 ? 0 : top + "px";
```

Comment: make sure you handled the browser resize & orientation change event.